# How to get all files shared with and shared by a user in Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, office-365-developer, microsoft-teams

I'm looking to develop a solution which shows all files that has been shared by the user or with the user in Office 365 (through OneDrive, Teams, SharePoint). How do I fetch this info? It should be something like the Audit report of OneDrive but also with files from other sources. The idea is to create a page/ app that shows all these files to the user.

Comment: It's really annoying there isn't a cleaner answer for this. In google drive you just punch in **from:username@gmail.com** or **to:username@gmail.com** in the search bar. C'mon Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft 365 auditing log has the records of all sharing events containing the target user and the acting user. For more information, you may have a check on this official doc. It could be a useful data for you to fetch.

[Use sharing auditing in the audit log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-sharing-auditing?view=o365-worldwide)